# Access denied in Website

Tags: wordpress, web-hosting

I have created a website using wordpress. But mw I'm getting an error displaying that my site access is denied. When I asked my hosting provider, they said that all my files are attacked by malware and they are asking to remove those files. How can I recover from this without deleting my files from the server. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Very important lesson: Never completely trust 3rd party software completely. Always have a local copy of it. Have your tried looking for the following documentation: http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/beginners-guide-how-to-restore-wordpress-from-backup/

Comment: I have not taken a backup of any of my files. But the site you mentioned are asking to restore the backup file. Is there any way to do it without taking a backup ?

Comment: Secondly it is not safe to download that files too! It might corrupt your local base too!

Comment: Then what should i do ? Should i create a new website from scratch ?

Comment: Yes, Strongly recommended. And try to build it locally. and deploy it when required.

Comment: Okay thanks for the information.

Comment: And lastly you want to check this thread. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/malware-attack-and-not-able-to-access-admin-or-blog/

Answer (score 0):

> you have to follow below points -
>
> 1) take complete backup of files and scan for virus.
>
> 2) update your wordpress with latest version, also update all plugins
>   and current theme with latest version.
>
> 3) change your wp-admin password, database username and password, also
>   change your ftp and cpanel credentials.
>
> 4) check files and folders permission, your .htaccess and
>   wp-config.php file should be permission 444.
>
> 5) install malware protection and security plugins.
>
> 6) Check header, footer, function and all javascript files for
>   unwanted code (mostly virus attack have on javascript code).

Comment: I cannot login to my site. I'm not able to view the wp-login page. If i can login into that, i can install those plugins and i can take a backup. So i need a solution for that.

Comment: can you login into cpanel or ftp? if yes so replace wp-admin and wp-include folder with latest version...
after it you will be able to login, you can take backup from cpanel (file manager also)

Comment: But all my files have already been affected by malware. Even if i take a backup of those files and if i reinstall those files, I may have the same problem right ?

Comment: No, There will be no issue.
I provided steps to work manually (from cpanel or file manages), When you replace core files with fresh files so malware will also removed. and you can access admin login. After you have to perform theme section than plugins.

malware mostly attach on core files and theme javascript section.